Why is multi-threaded, chunked writing of a large file slower when writing from many cores rather than the same core?
Note: the question has undergone some edits, taking into account numerous suggestions and findings from the comments, which may now appear outdated. It initially focused on the number of threads, while the actual problem seems to be threads' core affinities.
(I bet your intuitive answer is "synchronization" - bear with me as I reason why this is not necessarily the answer.)
The below code compares writing exactly the same data to a file: essentially, N times the same 1 MB chunk until the 10 GB target file size is reached. It does so from a variable number of threads (1 through 56), taking care of starting all threads simultaneously and measuring the time spent in filebuf::sputn calls.
(Because this has come up in the comments several times: the aim is not to write data faster than in a single thread. The aim is to write the data generated in several independent data generation threads, ideally without requiring another separate writing thread.)
Find also below the output from the code, generated on Windows using MSVC, a Samsung MZWL63T8HFLT-00AW7 SSD, and an Intel Xeon w9-3495X CPU (hyper-thread disabled, hence the limit of 56 threads), which I graphed using https://www.desmos.com/calculator. In essence, you see that if threads are assigned each to their own core, the time spent writing the file depends on the number of threads from which filebuf::sputn is called, which I am at a loss to explain since locking the mutex is excluded from the writing-time measurement, and the comparison of file-writing and overall durations indicates that locking amounts to not more than 2% of the total time anyway.
If all threads are assigned to the same core, the problem is not seen. Unfortunately, while this may be a solution in this toy example, it is not applicable in a real-world scenario where each thread generates its own data using expensive CPU operations.
Is that an expected result? What are strategies to avoid such performance when writing from multiple cores, apart from maybe the obvious (have all threads dump their data into a queue, with a separate thread emptying the queue and writing the file)?
Further testing showed this effect is strongly impacted by the Windows Power Plan. Below results (40% write rate reduction) have been collected under the "Balanced" plan; under the "Ultimate" plan, the effect is still seen, although smaller (15% reduction). Same results are obtained by writing to an ImDisk RAM disk, so it seems independent of the SSD.
Time spent in filebuf::sputn calls vs. number of threads
blue: each thread uses their own core
red: all threads use the same core

Code
#include <Windows.h>

#include <chrono>
#include <format>
#include <fstream>
#include <iosfwd>
#include <iostream>
#include <latch>
#include <mutex>
#include <ranges>
#include <ratio>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;
using double_milliseconds = duration<long double, milli>;

int main() {
    constexpr auto maxNThreads = 56;
    constexpr auto fileSize = 10'000'000'000;
    constexpr auto chunkSize = 1'000'000;

    mutex mutex;
    vector<jthread> threads;
    for (const auto sameCore : {false, true}) {
        for (const auto nThreads : ranges::iota_view(1, maxNThreads + 1)) {
            filebuf file;
            file.open("out.tmp", ios::out | ios::binary);

            latch commonStart(nThreads + 1);

            streamsize written = 0;
            nanoseconds writing{0};
            for (const auto i : ranges::iota_view(0, nThreads)) {
                const auto threadSize = fileSize / nThreads;
                threads.emplace_back([&commonStart, &mutex, &file, &written, &writing, threadSize, sameCore, i] {
                    const auto mask = static_cast<DWORD_PTR>(1) << (sameCore ? 0 : i);
                    if (!::SetThreadAffinityMask(::GetCurrentThread(), mask)) return;

                    const vector<char> chunk(chunkSize);
                    streamsize writtenThread = 0;
                    commonStart.arrive_and_wait();
                    while (writtenThread < threadSize) {
                        const lock_guard lock(mutex);
                        const auto write_start = steady_clock::now();
                        const auto writtenIteration = file.sputn(chunk.data(), chunk.size());
                        const auto write_stop = steady_clock::now();

                        writtenThread += writtenIteration;
                        written += writtenIteration;
                        writing += write_stop - write_start;
                    }
                });
            }

            commonStart.arrive_and_wait();
            const auto start = steady_clock::now();
            threads.clear();
            file.close();
            const auto stop = steady_clock::now();

            const auto cores = sameCore ? "same core" : "diff. cores";
            const auto written_gb = static_cast<double>(written) / 1'000'000'000;
            const auto duration = duration_cast<milliseconds>(stop - start);
            const auto rate_mb_s = static_cast<int>(static_cast<double>(written) / (double)duration.count() / 1000);
            const auto writing_ms = duration_cast<milliseconds>(writing);
            const auto writing_pct = static_cast<int>(duration_cast<double_milliseconds>(writing) / duration * 100);
            cout << format(
                "{:2d} threads(s), {}: {:.03f} GB / {} = {} MB/s ({} or {}% writing)",
                nThreads,
                cores,
                written_gb,
                duration,
                rate_mb_s,
                writing_ms,
                writing_pct
            ) << endl;
        }
    }
}

Output
 1 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.000 GB / 1825ms = 5479 MB/s (1824ms or 99% writing)
 2 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.000 GB / 1826ms = 5476 MB/s (1819ms or 99% writing)
 3 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.002 GB / 1897ms = 5272 MB/s (1887ms or 99% writing)
 4 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.000 GB / 1838ms = 5440 MB/s (1826ms or 99% writing)
 5 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.000 GB / 1893ms = 5282 MB/s (1880ms or 99% writing)
 6 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.002 GB / 1999ms = 5003 MB/s (1885ms or 94% writing)
 7 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.003 GB / 1919ms = 5212 MB/s (1903ms or 99% writing)
 8 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.000 GB / 2013ms = 4967 MB/s (1927ms or 95% writing)
 9 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.008 GB / 1969ms = 5082 MB/s (1953ms or 99% writing)
10 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.000 GB / 1972ms = 5070 MB/s (1956ms or 99% writing)
11 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.010 GB / 1982ms = 5050 MB/s (1966ms or 99% writing)
12 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.008 GB / 1986ms = 5039 MB/s (1969ms or 99% writing)
13 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.010 GB / 2116ms = 4730 MB/s (2099ms or 99% writing)
14 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.010 GB / 2086ms = 4798 MB/s (2055ms or 98% writing)
15 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.005 GB / 2080ms = 4810 MB/s (1997ms or 96% writing)
16 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.000 GB / 2185ms = 4576 MB/s (2095ms or 95% writing)
17 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.013 GB / 2126ms = 4709 MB/s (2109ms or 99% writing)
18 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.008 GB / 2236ms = 4475 MB/s (2181ms or 97% writing)
19 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.013 GB / 2212ms = 4526 MB/s (2133ms or 96% writing)
20 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.000 GB / 2185ms = 4576 MB/s (2168ms or 99% writing)
21 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.017 GB / 2192ms = 4569 MB/s (2174ms or 99% writing)
22 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.010 GB / 2171ms = 4610 MB/s (2152ms or 99% writing)
23 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.005 GB / 2172ms = 4606 MB/s (2154ms or 99% writing)
24 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.008 GB / 2290ms = 4370 MB/s (2271ms or 99% writing)
25 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.000 GB / 2281ms = 4384 MB/s (2262ms or 99% writing)
26 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.010 GB / 2372ms = 4220 MB/s (2352ms or 99% writing)
27 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.017 GB / 2368ms = 4230 MB/s (2349ms or 99% writing)
28 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.024 GB / 2362ms = 4243 MB/s (2343ms or 99% writing)
29 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.005 GB / 2361ms = 4237 MB/s (2341ms or 99% writing)
30 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.020 GB / 2388ms = 4195 MB/s (2369ms or 99% writing)
31 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.013 GB / 2297ms = 4359 MB/s (2277ms or 99% writing)
32 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.016 GB / 2274ms = 4404 MB/s (2255ms or 99% writing)
33 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.032 GB / 2306ms = 4350 MB/s (2286ms or 99% writing)
34 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.030 GB / 2341ms = 4284 MB/s (2321ms or 99% writing)
35 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.010 GB / 2404ms = 4163 MB/s (2383ms or 99% writing)
36 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.008 GB / 2555ms = 3917 MB/s (2446ms or 95% writing)
37 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.027 GB / 2461ms = 4074 MB/s (2440ms or 99% writing)
38 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.032 GB / 2508ms = 4000 MB/s (2488ms or 99% writing)
39 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.023 GB / 2470ms = 4057 MB/s (2449ms or 99% writing)
40 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.000 GB / 2543ms = 3932 MB/s (2521ms or 99% writing)
41 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.004 GB / 2549ms = 3924 MB/s (2528ms or 99% writing)
42 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.038 GB / 2592ms = 3872 MB/s (2570ms or 99% writing)
43 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.019 GB / 2672ms = 3749 MB/s (2651ms or 99% writing)
44 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.032 GB / 2790ms = 3595 MB/s (2700ms or 96% writing)
45 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.035 GB / 2701ms = 3715 MB/s (2676ms or 99% writing)
46 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.028 GB / 2746ms = 3651 MB/s (2720ms or 99% writing)
47 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.011 GB / 2794ms = 3583 MB/s (2770ms or 99% writing)
48 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.032 GB / 2850ms = 3520 MB/s (2823ms or 99% writing)
49 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.045 GB / 2983ms = 3367 MB/s (2936ms or 98% writing)
50 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.000 GB / 2965ms = 3372 MB/s (2939ms or 99% writing)
51 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.047 GB / 2904ms = 3459 MB/s (2879ms or 99% writing)
52 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.036 GB / 2893ms = 3469 MB/s (2866ms or 99% writing)
53 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.017 GB / 3011ms = 3326 MB/s (2981ms or 99% writing)
54 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.044 GB / 2856ms = 3516 MB/s (2830ms or 99% writing)
55 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.010 GB / 2917ms = 3431 MB/s (2891ms or 99% writing)
56 threads(s), diff. cores: 10.024 GB / 2857ms = 3508 MB/s (2829ms or 99% writing)
 1 threads(s), same core: 10.000 GB / 1805ms = 5540 MB/s (1804ms or 99% writing)
 2 threads(s), same core: 10.000 GB / 1796ms = 5567 MB/s (1817ms or 101% writing)
 3 threads(s), same core: 10.002 GB / 1814ms = 5513 MB/s (1813ms or 99% writing)
 4 threads(s), same core: 10.000 GB / 1800ms = 5555 MB/s (1798ms or 99% writing)
 5 threads(s), same core: 10.000 GB / 1798ms = 5561 MB/s (1822ms or 101% writing)
 6 threads(s), same core: 10.002 GB / 1777ms = 5628 MB/s (1814ms or 102% writing)
 7 threads(s), same core: 10.003 GB / 1789ms = 5591 MB/s (1786ms or 99% writing)
 8 threads(s), same core: 10.000 GB / 1789ms = 5589 MB/s (1830ms or 102% writing)
 9 threads(s), same core: 10.008 GB / 1825ms = 5483 MB/s (1809ms or 99% writing)
10 threads(s), same core: 10.000 GB / 1810ms = 5524 MB/s (1804ms or 99% writing)
11 threads(s), same core: 10.010 GB / 1797ms = 5570 MB/s (1795ms or 99% writing)
12 threads(s), same core: 10.008 GB / 1848ms = 5415 MB/s (1845ms or 99% writing)
13 threads(s), same core: 10.010 GB / 1779ms = 5626 MB/s (1806ms or 101% writing)
14 threads(s), same core: 10.010 GB / 1786ms = 5604 MB/s (1816ms or 101% writing)
15 threads(s), same core: 10.005 GB / 1833ms = 5458 MB/s (1830ms or 99% writing)
16 threads(s), same core: 10.000 GB / 1829ms = 5467 MB/s (1826ms or 99% writing)
17 threads(s), same core: 10.013 GB / 1785ms = 5609 MB/s (1815ms or 101% writing)
18 threads(s), same core: 10.008 GB / 1789ms = 5594 MB/s (1825ms or 102% writing)
19 threads(s), same core: 10.013 GB / 1781ms = 5622 MB/s (1814ms or 101% writing)
20 threads(s), same core: 10.000 GB / 1768ms = 5656 MB/s (1803ms or 101% writing)
21 threads(s), same core: 10.017 GB / 1844ms = 5432 MB/s (1834ms or 99% writing)
22 threads(s), same core: 10.010 GB / 1822ms = 5493 MB/s (1818ms or 99% writing)
23 threads(s), same core: 10.005 GB / 1801ms = 5555 MB/s (1797ms or 99% writing)
24 threads(s), same core: 10.008 GB / 1796ms = 5572 MB/s (1832ms or 102% writing)
25 threads(s), same core: 10.000 GB / 1859ms = 5379 MB/s (1806ms or 97% writing)
26 threads(s), same core: 10.010 GB / 1791ms = 5589 MB/s (1827ms or 102% writing)
27 threads(s), same core: 10.017 GB / 1775ms = 5643 MB/s (1813ms or 102% writing)
28 threads(s), same core: 10.024 GB / 1798ms = 5575 MB/s (1830ms or 101% writing)
29 threads(s), same core: 10.005 GB / 1890ms = 5293 MB/s (1850ms or 97% writing)
30 threads(s), same core: 10.020 GB / 1755ms = 5709 MB/s (1785ms or 101% writing)
31 threads(s), same core: 10.013 GB / 1806ms = 5544 MB/s (1844ms or 102% writing)
32 threads(s), same core: 10.016 GB / 1799ms = 5567 MB/s (1826ms or 101% writing)
33 threads(s), same core: 10.032 GB / 1762ms = 5693 MB/s (1815ms or 103% writing)
34 threads(s), same core: 10.030 GB / 1776ms = 5647 MB/s (1813ms or 102% writing)
35 threads(s), same core: 10.010 GB / 1773ms = 5645 MB/s (1812ms or 102% writing)
36 threads(s), same core: 10.008 GB / 1826ms = 5480 MB/s (1863ms or 102% writing)
37 threads(s), same core: 10.027 GB / 1815ms = 5524 MB/s (1846ms or 101% writing)
38 threads(s), same core: 10.032 GB / 1823ms = 5503 MB/s (1830ms or 100% writing)
39 threads(s), same core: 10.023 GB / 1776ms = 5643 MB/s (1811ms or 102% writing)
40 threads(s), same core: 10.000 GB / 1769ms = 5652 MB/s (1807ms or 102% writing)
41 threads(s), same core: 10.004 GB / 1803ms = 5548 MB/s (1841ms or 102% writing)
42 threads(s), same core: 10.038 GB / 1852ms = 5420 MB/s (1841ms or 99% writing)
43 threads(s), same core: 10.019 GB / 1827ms = 5483 MB/s (1844ms or 100% writing)
44 threads(s), same core: 10.032 GB / 1787ms = 5613 MB/s (1817ms or 101% writing)
45 threads(s), same core: 10.035 GB / 1821ms = 5510 MB/s (1852ms or 101% writing)
46 threads(s), same core: 10.028 GB / 1814ms = 5528 MB/s (1842ms or 101% writing)
47 threads(s), same core: 10.011 GB / 1788ms = 5598 MB/s (1816ms or 101% writing)
48 threads(s), same core: 10.032 GB / 1794ms = 5591 MB/s (1820ms or 101% writing)
49 threads(s), same core: 10.045 GB / 1780ms = 5643 MB/s (1809ms or 101% writing)
50 threads(s), same core: 10.000 GB / 1776ms = 5630 MB/s (1841ms or 103% writing)
51 threads(s), same core: 10.047 GB / 1836ms = 5472 MB/s (1824ms or 99% writing)
52 threads(s), same core: 10.036 GB / 1890ms = 5310 MB/s (1835ms or 97% writing)
53 threads(s), same core: 10.017 GB / 1810ms = 5534 MB/s (1836ms or 101% writing)
54 threads(s), same core: 10.044 GB / 1783ms = 5633 MB/s (1815ms or 101% writing)
55 threads(s), same core: 10.010 GB / 1771ms = 5652 MB/s (1831ms or 103% writing)
56 threads(s), same core: 10.024 GB / 1793ms = 5590 MB/s (1820ms or 101% writing)


@NathanOliver That can't be true. The SSD is just a block device, it doesn't even have the concept of file.

@NathanOliver "writing a single file wont get any increase from using multiple threads" - that is understood. I am not trying to speed up file writing by using multiple threads. I just have data generated in different threads that I want to write into the same file, and I would like that to not be slower than writing the same data from a single thread.

Sorry, comment retracted, was thinking the Q was asking something else

Probably not related to your issue, but you shouldn't use high_resolution_clock for measuring elapsed time, use steady_clock instead. Note that modern CPUs single threaded performance typically decreases the more threads that are running due to lower boost frequencies

If you want to write data from multiple threads. 1) Allocate a big buffer 2) pre-calculate which blocks of memory which thread is allowed to write to (offset + size). 3) Once a part of the file is complete in memory you can use boost::asio to start writing blocks of data to disk (make sure the blocks of data you write line up with the DMA block size of your disk), and these chunks you can also pre-allocate. It is the fastest way I know how to write to disk.

Your single thread obviously maxes out the write speed of the drive, so adding additional threads will not add any benefit, but may instead incur synchronization overhead and stuff. Your time measurement is not the way it should be done though, you should measure the time it takes for the entire program to finish, not the time spent in "sputn". Also add a file flush at the end to makes sure everything actually was written to disk.

Try executing the sputn call while not holding the mutex lock so that the driver can manage the contention for the write buffer and only hold the lock while fetching the next chunk and updating the counters. (I notice you're always writing the same chunk of zeros).  I think you're guaranteeing that this memory needs to pass through a different core's cache each time because the data is not ready to be DMA'd because the buffer is full and you're accessing your mutex in round-robin fashion.  *Not 100% familiar with the architecture though. I'm just someone on the internet. :)

@SvenNilsson "Your single thread obviously maxes out the write speed of the drive, so adding additional threads will not add any benefit" - please see my comment above (answer to NathanOliver).

@SvenNilsson "you should measure the time it takes for the entire program to finish, not the time spent in sputn": if you look at the code, I do both, and the difference between them does not account for the difference in observed write rates.

My guess is the cache synchronization costs might contribute here. I would first of all avoid shared chunk, and have each thread allocate its own. It would give you more realistic measurements, and avoid part of cache interconnect cost that does not exist in real case where each thread has its own data.

@Wyck "Try executing the sputn call while not holding the mutex" this leads to the program hanging in Release mode, and throwing asserts in Debug mode, such as "Inconsistent Stream Count. Flush between consecutive read and write". I don't think sputn is thread-safe.

@MichaelEntin thanks for the suggestion. Moving const vector<char> chunk(chunkSize); inside the thread does not make a difference, unfortunately.

It may be some weird quirk of the filebuf implementation. I'd try with buffering disabled.

@DavidSchwartz it file.pubsetbuf(nullptr, 0) what you propose? That does not make a difference, neither before nor after file.open.

I also tried the Windows API (CreateFile, WriteFile, CloseHandle) with and without FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING. Same result.

@bers What happens if you use the winapi in asynchronous mode? With file opened and written to with OVERLAPPED operations. Note that imply you keep track of your own write position, with an std::atomic<size_t> for example. Also try blocking directly after the request to simulate synchronous ops (with GetOverlappedResult).

@ElderBug you mean file = CreateFile(, ...FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, ..), event = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);, OVERLAPPED overlapped; overlapped.hEvent = event; overlapped.Offset = 0xFFFFFFFF; overlapped.OffsetHigh = 0xFFFFFFFF; WriteFile(file, chunk.data(), chunk.size(), NULL, &overlapped); GetOverlappedResult(file, &overlapped, &writtenIteration, TRUE);? Same thing.

@bers Then maybe try with true asynchronous calls, without the GetOverlappedResult. Don't forget that you can't reuse the event and OVERLAPPED until the request is actually finished.

@ElderBug I tried asynchronous in the sense that I unlock the mutex before GetOverlappedResult, such that 56 threads can schedule up to 56 parallel, asynchronous writes. No luck. I also tried a few more ways (computing the overlapped offsets and unlocking the mutex before WriteFile, then never use GetOverlappedResult at all) to enable multiple parallel writes from the same thread: that code is a little dodgy since one should not let go overlapped go out scope, but the results are exactly the same as in all other cases...

Based on other weirdness I have seen with synchronization primitives, I would not be surprised if Windows puts the writing thread to sleep because it is waiting for the disk I/O to complete, and some Windows versions (W11) are notorious for taking a long time to wake up such threads under certain conditions, especially when you have many threads spread across cores. I once had to make my own mutex implementation based on events to mitigate such problems.

I'd also lean toward a quirk or bug in the system like wake up time on IO, maybe with spurious wake up, although I still don't see how it could impact that much. Maybe try with bigger write blocks (aligned too?). Alternatively, try memory mapped files, or try opening the file once for each thread, so that each thread has its own file handle. Overall I don't have much hope for this, seems like a deeper issue.

@SvenNilsson that sounds interesting. I replaced std::mutex by Windows' CreateMutex, and that aggravates the problem quite a bit (56 threads with a std::mutex: "10.041 GB / 3138ms = 3199 MB/s (3108ms or 99% writing)"; with CreateMutex: "10.041 GB / 6963ms = 1442 MB/s (5609ms or 80% writing)". It may well be that the choice of synchronization primitives plays a role here...

@bers Careful, std::mutex and Windows Mutex are very different. std::mutex is closer to Windows' CriticalSection. Also, this might be a long shot, but have you tried disabling your anti-virus program if any? AV can hook file accesses so...

@ElderBug (no AV on that system at all.) Yes, I have become aware of the particularities of the Windows mutex, but still: note how the time "spent writing" with 56 threads doubled (Windows mutex compared to std::mutex), even when starting the respective time measurements after locking the respective mutexes...

One of the real issues that I see, is that you're using a shared mutex between every thread. Essentially creating a queue for the threads to write independently. Secondly, even without the mutex, you would have a bottleneck effect having multiple threads write to the same file. So of course your timing will increase exponentially based on N threads, because in truth, they are not all writing at the same time.
A true test and solution to your multiple thread writing of a single data source would look something like this:

Split the data source based on N number of threads.
Have each thread write its data to a temporary file.
Finally, concatenate the files sequentially together in order the threads are spawned.


The measured time is only for the file.sputn call so the fact that this is all serialised with a mutex doesn't seem relevant

The question is not about how to max out write speeds. It's about why sequential writes are slowed down when they are split over multiple thread, even though contention is measured to be negligible.

The OP explicitly asked "What are strategies to avoid such performance drops", which I have given.

I don't think this answer is correct. First, "you're using a shared mutex between every thread" - so what is the issue with that? Please consider the measurement times contained in the question, which state that locking the mutex takes not more than 2% of the total  time.

"even without the mutex, you would have a bottleneck effect having multiple threads write to the same file" - obviously, yes, but that is the same bottleneck as a single thread writing. I don't want to be faster, I just don't want to be slower than a single thread.

Finally, your proposed solution will make the chunks in the file be ordered by thread, which is not intended.

@bers The file would still need to be synchronized between each thread. So the bottleneck for 1 thread vs 2-56 threads is NOT the same. A single thread writing allows the system to optimize sequential writes. Multiple threads leads to context switches giving you the performance hit you are seeing.

A context switch is 5µs, there is no way this is true.

@bers setting the affinity should certainly give you a bit better timing but will not completely fix the performance issue.

Setting all thread affinities to a different core SetThreadAffinityMask(GetCurrentThread(), 1 << iLocal) does not solve the problem. Setting it to the same core (SetThreadAffinityMask(GetCurrentThread(), 1)) makes the problem disappear. Quite impressive. @ElderBug, fyi.
